# JPanel in JScrollPane doesn't adjust size dynamically

Tags: java, swing, resize, jscrollpane

I have a JScrollPane and a JPanel.

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane_yst = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane_yst.setBorder(null);
    scrollPane_yst.setViewportBorder(null);
    panel.add(scrollPane_yst);

    JPanel panel_yst = new JPanel();
    panel_yst.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 1000));
    panel_yst.setBorder(null);
    panel_yst.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    scrollPane_yst.setViewportView(panel_yst);
    panel_yst.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel_yst, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

During runtime, I add other components to panel_yst, but it doesn't get bigger when the components exceed its size.
(Same problem with and without setting preferred size)

ANSWER:

I found the solution. The problem was, that I set the preferred size of the panels that I lateron added onto the panel inside the scrollpane.

Because of that, the size of those panels was messed up. Just dont set the PreferredSize of the components that you add onto the panel.

Comment: Don't artificially constrain the JPanel's preferred size. Let its layout managers and component preferred sizes do this for you.

Comment: Also a [mcve] would help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It does not matter wether I set the preferred size. Somehow the panel cant get bigger than the ScrollPane, also if I dont set it.

Comment: Then yes, create and post a valid [mre] in your question as suggested by @GeorgeZ. This will allow us to see and experience for ourselves what is not working and why. the link will explain what this is and how it can help you and us.

Comment: *"ANSWER:"* Should be below, rather than edited into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was, that I set the preferred size of the panels that I lateron added onto the panel inside the scrollpane.

Because of that, the size of those panels was messed up. Just dont set the PreferredSize of the components that you add onto the panel.